# Why does gpg4win's gpg-agent not authenticate me to ssh?

Tags: ssh, gpg4win, gpg-agent

## Preamble

My understanding of gpg and ssh is medium-technical as a programmer and crypto-fan, but I'm not a huge pro in either's nitty-gritty details like configuration, "trivia" like alphabet soup specs, magic variables, and interoperation. I've been through a few hours of reading guides and troubleshootings, and a few years of light linux server use, and I've gotten through much so far, but I'm stuck now.

## Goal

To set up gpg4win with a master key with 1 auth subkey, that lets me authenticate in git and ssh via `gpg-agent` with a password prompt via gpg4win.

## Sitrep

Windows 10 pc, linux server on LAN for testing. ssh, putty, kitty, and pageant already set up and working with an older gpg key + derived putty key of mine. Kleopatra shows everything to be working, password prompt and gpg-agent included. gpg4win 3.1.7, gnupg 2.2.15, putty/kitty 0.71.

I've generated a new master key `9B59` for myself using ECC (ed25519), Certify-only. Generated 2 ECC subkeys (1 Encrypt, 1 Authenticate+Sign).

AS subkey:

- id = `F3DC`
- keygrip = `3289...224A`
- `gpg --export-ssh-key ...` = `ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3Nz... openpgp:0x6146F3DC`.

AS subkey keygrip added to `~\gnupg\sshcontrol`, ssh key added to server's `~/authorized_keys`.

`gpg-agent` running with `--enable-putty-support --enable-ssh-support`. Trying to run `pageant` fails with an error that "pageant is already running", indicating that ssh support is online (and no, there is no instance of pageant running).

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env var = `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\S.gpg-agent.ssh`. This file exists, is always "last modified on" at the time of gpg-agent starting, and contains some binary foobar.

`gpg-connect-agent -r keyinfo_list.txt` reported (among other keys):
`S KEYINFO 3289...224A D - - - P - - -`

**Trying to authenticate to my ssh server at this point failed against my expectation with "no supported auth methods (publickey)", and did not prompt for my password via gpg4win.**

After performing an operation in Kleopatra to force the key to be loaded, the previous output changed to
`S KEYINFO 3289...224A D - - 1 P - - -`
so my AS subkey `F3DC` is correctly loaded and cached.

**At this point authentication through putty/kitty using "pageant" (= gpg-agent) still did not work.**

The putty event log of the failed login shows:

```
Event Log: Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Event Log: Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
```

## Q

Why is gpg-agent not offering to use my AS subkey despite it being loaded in gpg-agent, set in `sshcontrol`, and listed in my `authorized_keys`?

Comment: I have also tried the same process with an RSA subkey (in an ECC master key), and the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so turns out 2 things were wrong:

1. `sshcontrol` is very iffy yet silent about line endings (last line must end with a line terminator)
2. you have to start gpg-agent-connect with `--homedir <your gnupg folder>`

Comment: just confirming that I followed the steps in OP on a new computer and it worked right away. Having your key imported, adding it to sshcontrol (and obviously your server's authorized_keys), enabling ssh/putty support, and setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK is all you need to do.

Comment: Confirmed - I've also found that Kleopatra starts the agent properly with the home directory set. You may want to try that first